# How to get array elements in JavaScript from contract call with JSON-RPC returning an array?

Tags: solidity, javascript, json-rpc

I have a function in my Solidity contract whose prototype is:

`function checkLastCustomerInvoices() public view returns (bytes32 [] memory)`

When I call it from the Truffle console it returns an array of elements, namely :

truffle(development)> myContractInstance.checkLastCustomerInvoices();
[ '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000657567656f74',
  '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000656e61756c74',
  '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000065726365646573' ]

When I call it from the browser with JSON-RPC, with the JavaScript code :

```
function checkLastCustomerInvoices()
{
    myContractInstance.checkLastCustomerInvoices(function(err,res){
           if (err)
                   console.log(err);
                else
                     {  
                        console.log(res);
                     }
       }
     );
    return false;
}
```

It returns in my browser's console:

```
function checkLastCustomerInvoices()
Array [ "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020" ]
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000657567656f740000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000656e61756c740000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000065726365646573"}
```

So the result returned by JSON-RPC seems to be a string that concatenates in some way :

```
0x
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000657567656f74
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000656e61756c74
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000065726365646573
```

Besides the 0x,
The first line is 32 (what use ?)
The second line the number of elements
and the 3 other lines my array elements.

Where is described this encoding ?
Is there a standard JavaScript method used to parse this string to a JavaScript array ?

Thanks

Comment: I guess 32 is for bytes32 : size of each array element..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this from a browser, but from a (client-side) node script, you can do:

```
const web3_eth_abi = require("web3-eth-abi");
const array = web3_eth_abi.decodeParameter("uint256[]", yourReturnedObject.result);
```

Comment: Thanks, this could be a trail, but I'm looking for a solution in JSON-RPC and don't know if I can use web3.js on on remote ethereum client side. The documentation (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#returns-24) states that any call is returned as string of DATA without any further information on its formatting. So I guess there must be some hidden documentation somewhere, but I'm unable to fin it...

Comment: @humhum: Yes, but you can take that string and convert it into an object via `obj = JSON.parse(str)`.

Comment: Don't get it : obj=JSON.parse(str) will make an object from a string containing JSON syntax. It won't in any case create an object from 'result' whose formatting comes from JSON-RPC …

Comment: @humhum: It should create a JSON object with a `result` field.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't change the problem: the result object field still contains that string:
Proof: In the console: (used elipses instead of real characters to shorten the comment..)
>>obj=JSON.parse('{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x ......"}');
Object { id: 1, jsonrpc: "2.0", result: "0x..." }
>>obj.result
"0x...."

Comment: Got further.
Checked that I get this `res` string directly from the `responseText` field of the XMLHttpRequest. I send a POST request with an eth_call. So no nasty post processing as I feared. NB : I make my call against Ganache 1.2.2. If it helps…

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are encoded with a 32 bytes denoting a position (offset) from the beginning of the data.
Then at that offset you will find another 32 bytes showing the length. After that you will have all the array elements.

In your case the first 32 bytes show an offset of 0x20 = 32, then at position 32 we have another 32 bytes showing the length of 1, and then 1 record of 32 bytes encode the actual element.

Find a detailed example below to understand this better.

The following article explains this in more detail:
https://medium.com/@hayeah/how-to-decipher-a-smart-contract-method-call-8ee980311603

```
> encode_abi(
  ["uint256[]", "uint256[]", "uint256[]"],
  [[0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3], [0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3], [0xc1, 0xc2, 0xc3]]
).hex()
/************* HEAD (32*3 bytes) *************/
// arg1: look at position 0x60 for array data
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060
// arg2: look at position 0xe0 for array data
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0
// arg3: look at position 0x160 for array data
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000160
/************* TAIL (128**3 bytes) *************/
// position 0x60. Data for arg1.
// Length followed by elements.
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a1
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a2
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a3
// position 0xe0. Data for arg2.
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b1
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b2
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b3
// position 0x160. Data for arg3.
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c1
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c2
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c3
```